# What are adjectives for "a group that grows fast", and "a group that is comparatively static"?

Tags: adjectives, quantifiers

The context is: I have an app where there are entries, sorted in tables. Think "Employees" and "Sales":

The "Employees" table is mostly static. It might go up or down a little bit month by month, but it will not see a lot of changes.

The "Sales" table, however, can have millions of new entries every month, on a successful business. And it can grow very quickly.

I'm looking for adjectives to categorize these differences, in order to write a phrase such as:

> Employees is ????, so it can be hosted in a regular database, while Sales is ???? and is better served by a data warehousing solution (for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already used [*static*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/static) for the first table

> **static**
> <sub>ADJECTIVE</sub>
>
> lacking in movement, action, or change

So for the second table I suggest using [*dynamic*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/dynamic)

> **dynamic**
> <sub>ADJECTIVE</sub>
>
> characterized by constant change, activity, or progress

Your sentence becomes

> The Employees table is **static**, so it can be hosted in a regular database, while the Sales data is **dynamic** and is better served by a data warehousing solution (for example).

Comment: Ok to static, but I believe "dynamic" covers the variability but not the high-volume part. Perhaps I will combine your answer with mine: *Employees is static and low-cardinality, while Sales is dynamic and high-cardinality.

Comment: While they might be in a dictionary, your two phrases aren't ones that, as a native English speaker, I have ever seen used in practice. Anyway, it's unlikely that a sales table will have millions of new entries: at that scale the products will be sold by the case, pallet, or container.

Comment: Let's not get marred by the example. I used Employees and Sales because I thought people would understand those better than my real entities, which have much more obscure names. I can assure you they are different in the way I described. You could switch Sales by "Log Entries" if it makes more sense for you. The question would remain the same.

Comment: Anyway, I am accepting this as the answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Someone told me *cardinality* might be the word I am looking for. As in:

> Employees is *low-cardinality* while Sales is *high-cardinality*.

Comment: No. Cardinality is to do with numbers of records, not growth rate. A large table (high cardinality) may still be largely static.

Comment: I see your point, but I also think that the answer is at least *partially right*. I think the downvote was a bit unmerited.